# Add search dropdown for React table in JHipster

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jhipster

I have this React table in JHipster project:

```
<div className="table-responsive">
        {activePairsList && activePairsList.length > 0 ? (
          <Table responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className="hand" onClick={sort('id')}>
                  ID <FontAwesomeIcon icon="sort" />
                </th>                
                <th className="hand" onClick={sort('exchangeId')}>
                  Exchange Id <FontAwesomeIcon icon="sort" />
                </th>
                ...........
                <th />
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {activePairsList.map((activePairs, i) => (
                <tr key={`entity-${i}`} data-cy="entityTable">
                  <td>
                    <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${activePairs.id}`} color="link" size="sm">
                      {activePairs.id}
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                  <td>{activePairs.exchangeId}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        ) : (
          !loading && <div className="alert alert-warning">No Active Pairs found</div>
        )}
      </div>
```

I would like to add search functionality for this table. I want to add Filter by `exchange` to be present and when any exchange is selected the table should be filtered to show only data for the selected exchange. Do you know how this can be implemented?

Comment: Dear @user1285928, thanks for putting your question on SO to share a problem and it's solutions to others. it's better to upvote someone who spent time for your problem and if it helps you mark it as accepted answer and assign the bounty to her/him. thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, my answer is completely enough according to your question details. But you asked an extra question in the same post (as lazy-loading) after giving my answer. That's not good for responders. You should give more detail when creating your question. Because we waste time. Anyway, I have shared my own lazy-loading example with you to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked on your issue in `stackblitz`. I create a link to a simple sample of what you want you can check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xwkyjy?file=src/App.js).
I've added an input to filter data is passing to the table on input changes. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Dear @ghazalkhaki, welcome to SO, thanks for your great answer and appreciate for spending time to solving others' problem, I hope you will be one of high-rank SO accounts in close feature. also, it's better to put important part of code in the answer. because by any reason outer-links maybe corrupted, so keeping code here is more safe. have good time.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right, I will do that in further answers. thanks for advising.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a **ReactJS/Typescript** solution and implemented it on the **JHipster 7**.

> NOTE: if you have no active-pairs entity, apply the below steps.Else continue from step 4.

First of all, [create a monolith web project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lf64CctDAQ) with JHipster 7 & ReactJS.

1. Create an entity of ActivePairs with [JDL Studio](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/) and download
   the JDL file from the JDL Studio. (`activepairs-jdl.jdl`)

> If you want to pagination add this expression in your jdl file : paginate all with pagination

[image: JDL Studio - entity generator]

2. Copy the `activepairs-jdl.jdl` file to the root folder of your
   project.
3. Open a terminal on the root folder of your project and write below command:

   `jhipster jdl activepairs-jdl.jdl`
4. Go this path in your project :
   `src>main>webapp>app>entities>active-pairs>active-pairs.tsx`
5. Copy the below code and paste it in your `active-pairs.tsx` file.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Col, Row, Table } from 'reactstrap';
import { ICrudGetAllAction, ICrudSearchAction } from 'react-jhipster';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import { IRootState } from 'app/shared/reducers';
import { getEntities } from './active-pairs.reducer';
import { IActivePairs } from 'app/shared/model/active-pairs.model';
import { APP_DATE_FORMAT, APP_LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT } from 'app/config/constants';

export interface IActivePairsProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ url: string }> { }

export const ActivePairs = (props: IActivePairsProps) => {


  useEffect(() => {
    props.getEntities();
  }, []);
  const { activePairsList, match, loading = true } = props;
  const myDataSource = props.activePairsList;

  const [myActivePairsList, setActivePairsList] = useState(props.activePairsList);
  const [dropdownList, setDropdownList] = useState([])
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false)

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('')
  const [arrOfSelectedExId, setArrOfSelectedExId] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const unrepeated = activePairsList.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc.find(item => item.exchangeId === curr.exchangeId)) {
        return acc
      }
      return acc.concat(curr)
    }, [])

    const regexes = [`${searchValue}`];
    const filtered = unrepeated.filter(item => regexes.some(regex => item.exchangeId.match(regex)));
    setDropdownList(filtered);
    setActivePairsList(activePairsList);
  }, [searchValue, activePairsList])

  useEffect(() => {

    if (arrOfSelectedExId.length) {
      setActivePairsList(myDataSource.filter(activePairs => {
        return arrOfSelectedExId.includes(activePairs.exchangeId)
      }))
    } else {
      setActivePairsList(myDataSource)
    }
  }, [arrOfSelectedExId])



  return (
    <div>
      <input value={searchValue} onFocus={() => setFocus(true)} onBlur={(e) => setFocus(false)} onChange={e => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} />
      {(dropdownList.length !== 0) && focus && (<div className="dropdown-parent">
        {
          dropdownList.map((item, i) => {
            return <div key={'drp' + i} className={arrOfSelectedExId.includes(item.exchangeId) ? 'selected' : ''} onMouseDown={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault()
              setArrOfSelectedExId(prev => {
                if (prev.includes(item.exchangeId)) {
                  return prev.filter(x => x !== item.exchangeId)
                } else {
                  return prev.concat(item.exchangeId)
                }
              })
              // setSearchValue(item.exchangeId)
            }}>{item.exchangeId}</div>
          })
        }
      </div>)}
      <h2 id="active-pairs-heading">
        Active Pairs
        <Link to={`${match.url}/new`} className="btn btn-primary float-right jh-create-entity" id="jh-create-entity">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="plus" />
          &nbsp; Create new Active Pairs
        </Link>
      </h2>
      <div className="table-responsive">
        {myActivePairsList && myActivePairsList.length > 0 ? (
          <Table responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Exchange Id</th>
                <th />
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {myActivePairsList.map((activePairs, i) => (
                <tr key={`entity-${i}`}>
                  <td>
                    <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${activePairs.id}`} color="link" size="sm">
                      {activePairs.id}
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                  <td>{activePairs.exchangeId}</td>
                  <td className="text-right">
                    <div className="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
                      <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${activePairs.id}`} color="info" size="sm">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">View</span>
                      </Button>
                      <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${activePairs.id}/edit`} color="primary" size="sm">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="pencil-alt" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Edit</span>
                      </Button>
                      <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${activePairs.id}/delete`} color="danger" size="sm">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Delete</span>
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        ) : (
          !loading && <div className="alert alert-warning">No Active Pairs found</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ activePairs }: IRootState) => ({
  activePairsList: activePairs.entities,
  loading: activePairs.loading,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getEntities,
};

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ActivePairs);
```

6. copy below css codes in your app.scss file :

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.selected {
  background-color: rgb(190, 188, 188);
}
.dropdown-parent {
  max-height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;  
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

7. Run this command `./mvnw`

- You should see a search box at the top of your table.

[image]

- As you see I selected 98 and It listed just the rows which have the
  values of ExchangeID is 98

[image]

*Thanks.*

Comment: Thanks for the example. There is one more thing which is not clear: The table that I have is using lazy loading to get the data into pages. Looks like I need to make the sort into SQL query(execute SQL query after I select item into the drop down list). How I can implement this?

Comment: @user1285928 did you implement it on your JHipster project?

Comment: No, I'm waiting your update.

Comment: It was a different challenge. But you had asked just adding search on react table. So I can share my lazy loading sample with ReactJs :  https://github.com/omurthy/next-saerch